Classifying a second order non-linear ODE
I am currently dealing with the following ODE as a stationary, special case version of a PDE model derived from Kuramoto-Sivashinsky.
$$
y'' y' = ay
$$
Where $a$ is a real (constant) parameter.
I am going through different handbooks (even asked chatgpt haha) to try and classify this equation or even (best case scenario) find some insight on analytical solutions/solution properties. However, this search has not provided much yet and I'm currently working on the linearization.
Has anyone here stumbled across a similar ODE before? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Multiply by $y'$ to get $$\frac{1}{3} (y'^{3})' = \frac{1}{2} a (y^{2})'$$ then integrate, then separate and integrate again. It might not be a nice integral though.

Yup, tried subbing m = y'(x) and then integrating once more but mathematica spit out a crazy special function solution.
I guess that's just the way the solution is.
I will give your  idea a try in a moment as well. Thanks!

Ah, leads to the same spot with the sub :) Thanks again Matthew

This type is classified as missing $x$. Let $p=y'=\frac{dy}{dx}$ and then
$$ y''=p'=\frac{dp}{dx}=\frac{dp}{dy}\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dp}{dy}p. $$
So the equation becomes
$$ \frac{dp}{dy}p^2=ay $$
or
$$ p^2dp=aydy. $$
So
$$ \frac13p^3=\frac12ay^2+C_1$$
and hence
$$ (y')^3=\frac32(y^2+C_1)$$
or
$$ y'=\sqrt[3]{\frac32}\sqrt[3]{y^2+C_1}$$
So
$$ \frac{dy}{\sqrt[3]{y^2+C_1}}=\sqrt[3]{\frac32}dx$$
Integrating gives the solution
$$ x=\sqrt[3]{\frac23}\int\frac{dy}{\sqrt[3]{y^2+C_1}}+C_2. $$

Thanks for the in depth answer! I was getting stuck at the final integral and mathematica is spitting some special function mess. I guess it's just not a "nice" integral.
Marking this as the final answer (and credit to  Matthew Cassell for his initial answer as well)
